# Remember password option in winform

Tags: winforms

Is there any way that I can put a checkbox of Remeber password in my winform as I have no tables for username and password.I am checking for the username and password directly in the server...

Answer please if am clear with my question.

Comment: Where would you propose that the password be stored ("remembered")? Or is that what you're asking us? What kind of application is it? Where is it going to be run?

Answer (score 0):

Most simplest way to do that would be to store the provided password in the [Application or User Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx). You may want to use some kind of encryption so that it is not stored as plain text.

Comment: You're begging for a downvote by qualifying the need to encrypt the password. It's not a matter of "may want to use some kind of encryption so that it is not stored as plain text", but rather **need to** use some kind of encryption because you should **never** store passwords as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the [Windows Credentials Manager API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374791%28VS.85%29.aspx)

When you start you WinForms application you will get Windows Credential Manager dialog. You will also have Remember Password option on it. When you enter your credentials they will be safely stored with Windows.

Check this link to see how to get this done - http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4693/using-the-credential-management-api/2/

Comment: +1 This seems to be a better way of accomplishing the requirement.